# How to call other activity by clicking on an item under overflow icon in action bar

Tags: javascript, android

Hi guys am  facing some problems with code. I need to open a new activity when the item under the overflow icon is clicked in the action bar

Below i have my code

I would like to know what place i am doing wrong in my coding and what would be the solution for it

Thanks in advance

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
         android:id="@id/item_option1"
        android:title="option1"
        android:onclick="gotocontact">
        </item>
   </menu>

// Main xml file

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mohammadzakriya.actionbar2.MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 package com.example.mohammadzakriya.actionbar2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item ) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.item_option1:
                public void gotocontact(View view)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mohammadzakriya.actionbar2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Contact">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be fine:

```
@Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item ) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.item_option1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break; 

            default: 
                break; 
        } 
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
    }
```

Comment: Cool. You may want to close the question by selecting this as accepted answer.

Comment: yes but i also had to make changes in my android menu xml file . had to delete the part of android:onclick="gotocontact"...rest on making edits in ur given sugesstions the code worked fine

Comment: What changes you needed to make?

Comment: I had to delete the android:onclick="gotocontact" in the menu xlm file and applied the edits to the code which u had mentioned and the code worked fine .Thanks again for the sugesstion

Answer (score 0):

problem is with this code....

```
public void gotocontact(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

you are defining a method but not calling it....so method will not be executed....you have to define it in your activity and call it from onOptionItemSelected method like this....

```
package com.example.mohammadzakriya.actionbar2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item ) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.item_option1:
                gotocontact();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



          public void gotocontact()
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
}
```